# Show sms notification

Tags: android, notifications, sms

i programmed a fake sms sender and have problem to show sms notification after inserted,

i use this code to insert sms :

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", "123456");
values.put("body", "Test !");
values.put("status", -1);
values.put("date", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
```

and tested this code, but email app return force close :

```
Intent a = new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
byte[] by =(byte[])(SmsMessage.getSubmitPdu("123456", "123456", "Test !", false).encodedMessage);
Object[] vrs = {by};
a.putExtra("pdus",vrs);
sendBroadcast(a);
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace associated with the FC?

Comment: @slayton in emulator it's ok but don't show any notification, but when i tested it in phone return force close, thanks

Comment: Again can you post the stacktrace associated with the FC? If your phone is plugged in to your computer you should output messages posted to logcat

Comment: @slayton when i connected phone to computer with usb, adb return stop working, `adb.exe has stopped working` and in console : `adb]This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.`

Comment: http://www.thecompboy.com/2011/11/android-tutorial-logcat.html

Comment: @slayton i know it, see screen shot : http://up.vatandownload.com/images/t0cv1d2b3y22w3d0rbp.png